# Android Back Button doesn't work at all

Tags: android

I have a `Fragment Activity` hosting a `Map` and `ListActivity`. I wanna put a method when the back button is pressed on the `Activity`, but it seems it doesn't work at all. My `Log` isn't even printed on the `Stacktrace`.
I have no idea what's wrong actually.

Here's the method:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) {
           Log.e("Test","Back Button Clicked");

            this.finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: What if you put Log.d("Test","KeyCode " +keyCode); as the first line of your method?

Comment: May be the problem with your code is your parent activity gets the instance and your current activity doesnt get instance of Backpressed event... You can print the backpressed event in your parent activt and then check...

Comment: @RakeshGondaliya: so what would be your suggestion? putting the same keyDown method on all the children activities?

Comment: @Agarwal: where should I call that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-android-fragments  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992216/android-fragment-handle-back-button-press

Comment: yes, thank you for providing me the related link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted that sort of functionality you would need to override it in your activity, and then add a YourBackPressed interface to all your fragments, which you call on the relevant fragment whenever the back button is pressed.

Copied from [how to implement onBackPressed() in Android Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-android-fragments)

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed(){ 
  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "back button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
  Log.e("Test","Back Button Clicked");
  this.finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to remove 'if' statement and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

try it , it may be works as per your need,

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                Log.e("Test","Back Button Clicked");
    Intent backpage = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,BackPageActivity.cls);
                    startActivity(backpage);
               CurrentActivity.this.finish();

                return true;
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

[How to implement onBackPressed() in Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-android-fragments)

In order to use the back button on a Fragment, you need to declare the `onKeyDown`/`onBackPressed()` method on your children Activities as well.