# How to disable back button pressed in android fragment class

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to disable the back button in a fragment class. `onBackPressed()` doesn't seem to work in this fragment. How could I disable the back button?

This is my sample code:

```
public class Login extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       ,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, null);
        return root;
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
    }
}
```

Comment: for fragment popbackstack() method is used..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

You need to use the new `OnBackPressedDispatcher` to handle on back callbacks. Then, you can show `Are you sure dialog` to confirm the action.

```
OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                // create a dialog to ask yes no questions whether or not the user wants to exit
            }
        };
    requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
```

**Old Answer**

*The below method is deprecated.*

You have to override `onBackPressed` of the parent `FragmentActivity` class. Therefore, put your codes in the parent `FragmentActivity`. Or you can call the parent's method by using this:

```
public void callParentMethod(){
    getActivity().onBackPressed();
}
```

in `FragmentActivity` override `onBackPressed` Method and not call its superclass to disable the back button.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  // super.onBackPressed();
  // create a dialog to ask yes no question whether or not the user wants to exit
  ...
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that although this is the accepted answer, these days the onBackPressed() method is deprecated in favour of the OnBackPressedCallback  explained in the other answers. More info here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity?hl=en#onBackPressed()

Answer (score 29):

Here is the new way you can manage your `onBackPressed()` in fragment with the new call back of activity:

```
    // Disable onBack click
    requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
      // With blank your fragment BackPressed will be disabled.
    }
```

Here is the android doc link: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcher

Comment: While this does work, it seems to set the callback for the whole activity, meaning that any fragment that is shown with this activity will have the back button disabled instead of just the current Fragment. (Perhaps worth noting I use .add instead of .replace when switching fragment)

Answer (score 13):

## OnBackPressedCallback

Here is the code which you can write in your Fragment class to customize the back button press.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true /* enabled by default */) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                // Handle the back button even
                Log.d("BACKBUTTON", "Back button clicks");
            }
        };

        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);

     }

}
```

### Relevant link

You can read and research more on this [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back)

Comment: Kotlin requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true)
        {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed()
            {
            }
        })

Answer (score 12):

In your parent Activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
    if (f instanceof yourfragment) {//the fragment on which you want to handle your back press
        Log.i("BACK PRESSED", "BACK PRESSED");
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: i was wondering how to use findFragmentById and now i know this too. Great

Answer (score 12):

In your oncreateView() method you need to write this code and in KEYCODE_BACk return should true then it will stop the back button option for particular fragment

```
     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xyz, container, false);
    //Back pressed Logic for fragment  
    v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);  
    v.requestFocus();  
    v.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {  
    @Override  
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                return true;  
            }  
        }  
        return false;  
    }  
});
```

Comment: It worked for me only when used `View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, null);`

Answer (score 9):

I know it's too late,
In fragment onCreate

```
val callback = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
Log.d("tag","back button pressed")    // Handle the back button event
}

callback.isEnabled
```

Comment: Yes! This should work: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

to

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

**OR**

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {

    onBackPressed();
}

return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

return;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just override `onBackPressed` in your fragment where you want to disable the back press.

More info here: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcher

```
public class Login extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                // Log.d("TAG", "Pressed...");
            }
        };
        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to fragment never closed without any button action you can try to prevent cancel Fragment.

In your fragment method add this

```
 this.setCancelable(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late but maybe this code helps someone works with kotlin.

- in the activity which contains your fragment override onBackPressed Function.
- check if your frameLayout Which will have the fragment is empty.
- if the container is empty, super.onBackPressed will call.

  ```
    override fun onBackPressed() {

    val frameLayout = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.yourFrameLayout)
    if (frameLayout == null) {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
   }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method;

```
private fun disableBackPress() {
    activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            // do nothing for disable back button
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put a transparent view and set onClickListener for it

Comment: Please put more detailed information for asker. code snippet could be good.

Comment: Just create a match_parent view and set background transparent. set onClickListener for this view and do nothing inside