# Disable Back Button press from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

My application has an activity with so many fragments. I want to disable the back button press in some fragment. I tried with the below code. But it doesn't work.

In the main activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        OrderFragment.onBackPress();
}
```

In the fragment,

```
public static void onBackPressed()
{
    Log.d(TAG,"It listen");
}
```

I have the log message but, how can I disable the back button from my fragment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable back button pressed in android fragment class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17738966/how-to-disable-back-button-pressed-in-android-fragment-class)

Answer (score 7):

You should keep a reference to the fragment you want to disable/handle back press event on your main activity:

```
class MainActivity{

    OrderFragment mOrderFragment;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mOrderFragment.isVisible())
            mOrderFragment.onBackPressed();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

In OrderFragment:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    //handle back press event
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v4.app.Fragment.isVisible()' on a null object reference` error.

Comment: Seem like your fragment reference is null. You should try to add a check null condition before calling isVisible()

Answer (score 6):

In your oncreateView() method you need to write this code and in KEYCODE_BACk return should true then it will stop the back button option for particular fragment

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xyz, container, false);
//Back pressed Logic for fragment   
v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);   
v.requestFocus();   
v.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {   
@Override   
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        return true;   
    }   
}   
return false;   
}    
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
getView().requestFocus();
getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) {

            // leave this blank in order to disable the back press 

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This may not work when there is a focusable view like EditText. perhaps we might need to add the key listener on that too..

Comment: @technoguff you are right this is not working when soft key board is activated, but what is the solution to overcome that? can you put the code too

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to Override onResume method in fragments which you need to disable the back press.Tryout the following code.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    this.getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    this.getView().requestFocus();
    this.getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried like this, Actually it works for me before.

you can set listener for Back key. if you add it, i guess it works.

```
youfragment.getView().setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
    {
        if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
} 
);
```

Answer (score 2):

`super.onBackPressed` in the activity is the default implementation. Remove this if you don't want it.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question and because of navigation components and new ways this situation rarely occurs, still, maybe my answer helps someone.

I came across a similar situation where I needed the back button to be disabled and I couldn't change the activity as well. So in a fragment, I added this code block.

Language: Kotlin

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    this.requireView().isFocusableInTouchMode = true
    this.requireView().requestFocus()
    this.requireView().setOnKeyListener { _, keyCode, _ ->
        keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
    }
}
```

This will disable your back press on that specific fragment

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    if (currentFragment instanceof YourFragment) {
         currentFragment.onBackPressed();
    } else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    val currentFragment = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).currentDestination?.id
    if (currentFragment == R.id.YourFragment) {
        return
    }
    super.onBackPressed()
```

Answer (score 0):

[`onBackPressed`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.onBackPressed%28%29) works like this:

```
public void More onBackPressed() {
    if (!mFragments.popBackStackImmediate()) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Thus when you call super.onBackPressed() you pop the BackStack before finishing the activity. The best way to sort this out is to make sure you do **not** add the fragments to the BackStack. It is normally done like this:

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(TAG);
```

An alternative solution, but uglier since you have still useless code left, would be making `onBackPressed()` directly call `finish()` to end the activity.

I would strongly advise you not use `getView().setOnKeyListener(...)` since it is code smell.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your fragment to be in the backstack you can do so, by not adding it to the backstack in the transaction. So do **NOT** call `FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack();` on the fragments you do not want in your backstack.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void onBackPressed() {
if (!mFragments.popBackStackImmediate()) {
finish();
}else{
super.onBackPressed();}

}
```