# Handling Back Button with Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my MainActivity, I am launching a fragment using the following:

```
private void displayView() {
        Log.d("displayView", "in select item");
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        fragment = new WorkoutsFragment();


        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.main_container, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack("fragBack")
                    .commit();
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
```

This loads my fragment correctly, and I am able to see it, however, when I hit the back button it exits the application.  I would like it to go back to MainActivity if possible.

Is this improper handling of a fragment?  If so, what would be the correct way of approaching this?

Thanks!

Comment: i think this link will same as your question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755550/fragment-pressing-back-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `onBackPressed` in your main activity and not call `super.onBackPressed`. In the overriden method, you can remove the fragment from the fragment manager.