# Handling Backpressed in Fragment which does not have an activity

Tags: android, fragment, onbackpressed

I have a navigation drawer & on click of certain items of navigation drawer, i am opening Fragment.These fragments does not have an activity. I have an edittext in my fragment,on click of it i am setting some view to invisible and on click of back button of keyboard i want to again show the view which were invisible on click of edittext.
My fragment does not have an activity so i cant implement onBackPressed. Please help

Comment: how could you attach the fragment in to the window without activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a listener in your fragment view doing this:

```
view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                // handle back button's click listener
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

[Referenced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755550/fragment-pressing-back-button/27145007#27145007)