# Up button (back button) between fragments with no actionbar

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on a project with only one activity, my activity has fragment container to swap between different fragments and thats it. I have like 15-20 fragments in the project and I want to be able have a back button between some of the fragments. As I do only have one activity and I have NoActionBar I was wondering if there is a way to have an up/back button between fragments. I have researched but not found an awnser.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do u use navigationUI?

Comment: No I do not actually.

Comment: I recommend u use NavigationUI. Its save you from brain storms)
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui

Comment: I am reading upon it, thanks I will try it!

Answer (score 0):

Try use the following inside the `onclick()` of the back button: `getActivity().onBackPressed();`

This question has also been answered here:[Fragment pressing back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755550/fragment-pressing-back-button/27145007#27145007).
Check that link for more insights.