# OnBack Press Fragment showing blank Screen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I am using Fragments in my Application.So on the home page i have a grid view of 5 item on selection of which again i am opening a new fragment .

So what is happening is on back press it is showing a blank screen after that it is closing the application .

Please suggest me what i have done wrong in this.

**MyCode**

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                if (DASHBOARD_LINKS[arg2].equals("A")) {
                    fragTran.replace(R.id.content_frame,
                                firstFrag);
                        fragTran.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                        fragTran.addToBackStack(null);
                        fragTran.commit();

                }
                if (DASHBOARD_LINKS[arg2].equals("B")) {
                    fragTran.replace(R.id.content_frame, secondFrag);
                    fragTran.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    fragTran.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragTran.commit();
                }
                if (DASHBOARD_LINKS[arg2].equals("C")) {
                    fragTran.replace(R.id.content_frame, thirdFarg);
                    fragTran.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    fragTran.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragTran.commit();
                }
            }
        });
```

Please help my this is happening

Comment: it's because you are adding nothing but `null` to your `fragTran.addToBackStack(null);` method

Comment: so what i have to do with this will u please suggest me something in this

Comment: I am not that clear in this but `fragTran.addToBackStack("Tag");` this  worked for me.

Comment: Just a `String` to identify a `Fragment`.Once again I am not fully clear on it.please read the documentation to get a clear idea.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132623/onback-pressed-data-not-showing-in-fragments

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My suggestion for you is that let `addToBackStack(null)` in the fragment call.

But remove this line 
 `addToBackStack(null)`

from the Homepage after which `onbackpress` you are getting the blank screen hope this will for you .

Comment: Though it is preferred answer. I don't understand what are you trying to say

Comment: Thanks, i know its been a year since this question was asked. but removing `addToBackStack(null) `for the first transition fixed mine.

Comment: @Developer, your answer is so confusing. I want to use onBackstackchangedlistener too, but if I remove addToBackStack then onBackstackchangedlistener never works.

Comment: Thats not the correct answer. Please follow this link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53813425/1298105

Comment: Solution is confusing.

Answer (score 5):

> Fragment showing blank solutions.

1. Make sure to add first Base Fragment without `addToBackStack`() method. Because it is responsible for **Navigation Back**. We don't want to go back from first Page. So don't add it to backStack.
2. While moving from **Fragment A to Fragment B** if you have call `fragmentTransacation.add` then while comming back from B to A. `onViewCreated` or `onResume` method will not called as you have added a fragment to it.  So in order to hit `onResume` or `onViewCreated` while going back to Fragment A. you should call fragmentTransaction.replace

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    if (fragments == 1) {
        finish();
    } else {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

addToBackStack()  <--dont include this for your first fragment.-->

```
if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() !=1){
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("placeholder");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to handle back button press. You can do the following,

before  transitioning between `Fragments`, call `addToBackStack()` like the following,

```
 fragTran.replace(R.id.content_frame, secondFrag);
                    fragTran.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    fragTran.addToBackStack("TAG");
                    fragTran.commit();
```

For clear info please see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/7992472/1665507

Comment: same issue it is showing a blank screen then it is closing the application

Comment: @PoojaDubey: Well I guess there is some other problem in your code, because the above way works.You can check the sample from here https://www.dropbox.com/s/iup67qfwkx5uzqo/FragmentsTest.rar

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you navigating fragment from one activity to the fragment of the second activity. And while replacing your fragment you are adding them into backstack, so don't add the first fragment of respective activities into backstack.

Answer (score 0):

Update your OncreateView() method :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (view != null) {
    if (view.getParent() != null) {
        ((ViewGroup)view.getParent()).removeView(view);
    }
    return view;
}

View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tests, container, false);
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Forgot to add. Declare View view; at the top