# How can I avoid using instanceof in this case?

Tags: java, android, fragment, instanceof

I've had to use `instanceof`several times here while checking what subclass a `Fragment` is, and I feel like I'm going wrong somewhere:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Fragment frag = mManager.findFragmentByTag("Fragment");

    if(frag instanceof CustFragmentOne || 
       frag instanceof CustFragmentTwo || 
       frag instanceof CustFragmentThree || 
       frag instanceof CustFragmentFour) {

            //This method displays an instance of "CustFragmentFive"
            displayView(0);
    }
    else if(frag instanceof CustFragmentFive)
         super.onBackPressed();

    else if(mManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

    else
       super.onBackPressed();

}
```

Is there any way around using it here? How else can I identify the fragment's type and accordingly invoke the right method?

Comment: The typical way of bypassing the need for the `instanceof` operator is the `Visitor pattern`

Comment: Looks to me like `CustFragmentOne`, `CustFragmentTwo`, `CustFragmentThree` and `CustFragmentFour` should all extend an interface that has some method to identify if the object needs to display the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to have CustFragmentOne, CustFragmentTwo, etc. implement a common interface. That way you just need to do a single instanceof check against that interface, instead of needing to check each concrete class individually.

Another way would be something like along these lines: [How to implement onBackPressed() in Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-android-fragments)

Comment: Got it... Also I've looked at that link before, but I find it pretty confusing, is there any simpler explanation you know of?

Answer (score 2):

Use an interface. For example:

```
public interface ICustomFragment {

      public boolean shouldNavigateBack();
```

And then you can do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

CustomFragment frag = (CustomFragment)mManager.findFragmentByTag("Fragment");

    if(frag.shouldNavigateBack()) {

            //This method displays an instance of "CustFragmentFive"
            displayView(0);
    }
    else {
         super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if(frag.getClass() == CustFragmentOne.class)` not sure which approach is better tho

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you keep your Fragment objects into your Activity?

```
CustFragmentOne fragment1 = (FragmentOne)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);  
 CustFragmentTwo fragment2 = (FragmentOne)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
```

and in your layout xml file you will have smth like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    ...>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.smartmirror.FragmentOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="com.smartmirror.FragmentTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use something like this to have control of the back button on the fragments:

1. Create a base fragment abstract class:

   ```
   public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

       public void onBackPressed() {

       }

   }
   ```
2. Extend all your fragments from BaseFragment

   public class CustFragmentOne extends BaseFragment {
       ...
   }
3. Change your activity

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {

       Fragment frag = mManager.findFragmentByTag("Fragment");

       if(frag instanceof BaseFragment)
           frag.onBackPressed();
       else if(mManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
           getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
       else
          super.onBackPressed();

   }
   ```
4. override in your fragments the onBackPressed() method with the logic you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could always create a BaseFragment that extends Fragment to be extend by all fragments. Then you can let each fragment handle it as necessary making it a bit cleaner.  e.g.

`public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Override this function in your fragment classes as needed
    }
 }`

or you could do something like ([Android Fragment handle back button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992216/android-fragment-handle-back-button-press))