# ListView in fragment to another listview

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to make a fragment consist of a listView

And when I click the listView's item, it would go to another listview

but if I use fragment with "replace" method

I cannot go back to the previous listview

And I just can't use Activity to Activity because the fragments are in the NavigationDrawer

Can someone tell me how to do that?

Comment: Technically, if you could add the second listview to the fragment backstack, then you could go back with replace().

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution could fix your problem. it's kinda similar problem to handle back button inside fragment [Android Fragment handle back button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992216/android-fragment-handle-back-button-press)