# How to Handle backPress with Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have Fragment Activity With contatin navigation drawer.after clicking navigation drawer item it open a Fragment 1, fragment 2, Fragment 3.and then after button click event in Fragment 1 open new Fragment 4.

i want handle back key press event how can i do this on Fragment 4?after clicking back key in  Fragment 4 i want to go back Fragment 1.

[image]

Comment: if you don't do any thing this must be happened, witch fragment opened after backPress ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992216/android-fragment-handle-back-button-press

Comment: no after backpress it open a my home layout which is `Fragment 2` it is set as main fragment in navigation drawer

Comment: please post some code, because i think if you don't change any thing pre fragment must be opened

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add Fragments To BackStack. Before commit() the transaction, use addToBackStack() method
i.e

```
 addToBackStack("Some String").commit();
```

and in onBackPressed()

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() { 
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(); 
    } else { 
        this.finish(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean like this `getFragmentManager()
   .beginTransaction()
   .replace(R.id.content_frame,
     Entry_Account.newInstance(), Entry_Account.TAG).addToBackStack()
   .commit();` inside my `Fragment 1` but it says `The method addToBackStack(String) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments ()`

Comment: In Activity onBackPressed() method if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount()>0){pop the fragment} else{super.onBackPressed();}

Comment: what do you mean in `{pop the fragment}`

Comment: remove fragment from stack like fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Adding fragment transactions to the backstack will reverse the transaction on back pressed.

Comment: Fragments don't get added to the backstack.  The transaction does.  Everything you do in a transaction (add, replace, remove, hide, etc.) will be reversed all at once if you push it on the stack and then pressed "back".

Comment: @Sameera Is it working for you? Yeah agree with above comment

Comment: i add this on your code's `{pop the fragment}` section `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();`

Comment: `@Override
     public void onBackPressed() {

   if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
      {
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    
          
      }
      else
      {
          this.finish();  
      }


         }`

Comment: `addToBackStack("Some string") .commit();`

Comment: I think

else { super.onBackPressed(); }

would provide a more graceful fallback than assuming Activity.finish(). Also, it's strange you need to implement this logic when using android.app.FragmentManager, but _not_ android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager. I received default back stack handling when using the support library version.

Comment: @damien5314 Oh my god this^ I just spent close to 2 hours trying to figure out what the hell had happened to my back stack and I had swapped from support fragments to normal ones recently. God dammit!

Answer (score 5):

Your code for adding fragment to backstack should be like:

```
getFragmentManager() .beginTransaction() .replace(R.id.content_frame, Entry_Account.newInstance(), Entry_Account.TAG).addToBackStack("Some string") .commit();
```

Then On Activity's onBackPressed method,use this snippet:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed () {
if(getFramentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()>0){
      // popback statck.
}
 else{
     // finish your activity.
 }
}
```

Comment: `@Override public void onBackPressed() { if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) { getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(); } else { this.finish(); } }`

Answer (score 4):

Override onBackPress() method and check that your fragement manager has backStack entry>0 if it has greater than 0 than do popback stack otherwise finish your activity..

```
if(getFramentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()>0){
      // popback statck.
}
 else{
     // finish your activity.
 }
```

don't forget to add your fragement to BackStack  to maintain fragment hierarchy..

```
fragTransacion.addToBackStack(TAG);
```

Comment: how can i add fragement to BackStack to maintain fragment hierarchy?