# Why I got onBackPressed issue in Android

Tags: android

when I click on the back press on real device it went to the home page not to the previous  page ,here I am Using fragments how to solve that issue

**In First Fragment**

```
NotesFragment notes = new NotesFragment();
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.day_fragment_mainLayout, notes);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

**in Second Fragment**

```
DayFragment day = new DayFragment();
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.replace(R.id.day_fragment_mainLayout, day);
transaction.commit();
```

**in Third Fragment**

```
ItemsFragment items = new ItemsFragment();  
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.replace(R.id.day_fragment_mainLayout, items);
transaction.commit();
```

when i click on backpress button its goes to the home page,bt i need prevoius page.

**note:** btnclick i am using to navigating fragments one to one

Comment: Please go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717127/how-to-handle-backpress-with-fragment/27717201#27717201

Comment: your first fragment is replaced by second fragment and second fragment is replaced by third fragment.. And when you are on third fragment and click on back button, you are navigated to home page instead of second fragment.. is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve it by using FragmentTransaction's `add()` method, and then override onBackPressed where you have to pop your FragmentManager's back stack. This will result in the behaviour you described.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot go back because you didn't open any new activity. OnBackPressed is moving you to the previous activity stored in the stack. If you want to go back to the previous fragment, you have to store the previous fragment somewhere and then use:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// here you should change the fragment
    transaction.replace(YOUR_PREVIOUS_FRAGMENT, items);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Thanks for attention!

Comment: when i use this transaction.replace(YOUR_PREVIOUS_FRAGMENT, items);
transaction.commit();

Comment: Please Help me any one

Comment: Ok, lets say you have 3 fragments: fragment1, fragment2, fragment3. When you open fragment 1, you should save it somewhere before opening new fragment(fragment2), lets say in a variable : int lastFragment; When you press back button, you just check the lastFragment and open a fragment stored there

Comment: forgot to say, you have to override the onBackPressed(){ transaction.replace(lastFragment, items);
transaction.commit();}

Comment: Yet not i didnt get a solution please help me any one

Comment: In First Fragment I have a button called addnote in side that button onclick i wrote this logic

Comment: private void NextFragment()
    {
        NotesFragment notes = new NotesFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_mainLayout, notes);
        transaction.commit();
    }

Comment: the code that i pasted should be in the activity.... actually I'm confused now =)

Comment: I got Answer i use getActivirty().onBackPressed();