# How to add tag to Fragment Transaction?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I'm adding a `Fragment` to my `Activity` like this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()              
            .add(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName())
            .commit();
```

But when I want to find the `Fragment` using a `FragmentManager` it's returning null:

```
 Fragment oldFragment = (Fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragment.getClass().getName());
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717127/how-to-handle-backpress-with-fragment/27717201#27717201

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You try to find it by tag, but you haven't given it any tag

if you want to give it a tag, do it like this

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()              
        .add(R.id.frame_container, fragment, "tagABC")
        .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
        .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName())
        .commit();
```

and then you can get it with

```
Fragment oldFragment = (Fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tagABC");
```

BTW, you should correct your question title, the problem has nothing related to backstack.

Comment: Thanks a lot man!
I just forget, that i should give tag at add method, not in addToBackStack

Comment: ic. Just FYI, the parameter of addBackStack() is for naming the backStack itself, where you can revert to a backStack directly if you have multiple of it.