# How to solve fragment Instantiate exception in android while pressing back button

Tags: android

In My application have activity with fragment and another activity with fragment if user press back button from second activity fragment .It should go to first activity fragment
I have tried using in fragment

```
getActivity.finish()
```

In activity 
finish()

I am getting fragment Instantiate exception

Thanks

Comment: i think android handles this scenario automatically on back pressed. What happens if you don't override `onBackpressed` and let android handle back press?

Comment: @abhisek it is going to fragment

Comment: Do not call `super.onBackPressed` in that case then just call `finish()` in `onBackpressed`Method of activity.

Comment: look into the following..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992216/android-fragment-handle-back-button-press

Comment: Use addtobackstack() in the first activity it will add the first activity into the stack.And on back press the first activity will be there.