# MaterialDrawer back button in fragment

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, materialdrawer

I use a `MaterialDrawer` from Mike Penz and i faced with problem.
I have `Activity (AppCompat)` and **3 Fragmnts**. `Activity` contain all `fragments`.
In `fragment` 2 and 3 i enable Back `button` in `OnCreate`

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and in `Activity`

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen())
            drawer.closeDrawer();
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            drawer.getActionBarDrawerToggle().syncState();
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

When active `fragment` 2 and 3 `click` on the `Back Button` leads to opening `Drawer` &
How can I disable the call `Drawer` in the 2 and 3 `fragment` by pressing the button `Back`?

When I used a standard `Drawer` I had a theme with `ActionBar`, there are no such problems.

**UPD** i need click in Toggle Back Button in Toolbar, no smartphone physical button

Comment: try this answer on stackoverflow............http://stackoverflow.com/a/7992472/3678308

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 if (drawer.isDrawerOpen())
     drawer.closeDrawer();
 if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
     drawer.getActionBarDrawerToggle().syncState();
     getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
 }
```

To

```
 if (drawer.isDrawerOpen())
     drawer.closeDrawer();
 else if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
     drawer.getActionBarDrawerToggle().syncState();
     getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
 }
```

You are good to go