# Display and use Back button in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

```html
public class NewFrag extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);


    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.newfrag, container, false);

    }

}
```

```js
public class PrimaryFragment extends Fragment {

    Button btn1;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.primary, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        btn1 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Fragment var1 = new NewFrag();
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).replaceFragment(var1);

            }
        });
    }


}
```

```css
public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

    public static TabLayout tabLayout;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    public static int int_items = 2 ;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });
    }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        /**
         * Return fragment with respect to Position .
         */

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            switch (position){
                case 0 : return new PrimaryFragment();
                case 1 : return new SocialFragment();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return int_items;

        }

        /**
         * This method returns the title of the tab according to the position.
         */

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0 :
                    return "Primary";
                case 1 :
                    return "Social";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    NavigationView mNavigationView;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /**
         *Setup the DrawerLayout and NavigationView
         */

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.shitstuff) ;

        /**
         * Lets inflate the very first fragment
         * Here , we are inflating the TabFragment as the first Fragment
         */

        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        /**
         * Setup click events on the Navigation View Items.
         */

        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();



                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_inbox) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new NavOne()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_sent) {
                    FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new NavTwo()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                }

                return false;
            }

        });

        /**
         * Setup Drawer Toggle of the Toolbar
         */

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout, toolbar,R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        mDrawerToggle.syncState();



    }

    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){
        FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        t.replace(R.id.containerView, fragment).addToBackStack(null);
        t.commit();
    }

    public void showArrow(){
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

This topic may look very old and there might be many answers but my situation is very unique. I have to implement Navigation Drawer and TabLayout in MainActivity. So I used this [tutorial](https://androidbelieve.com/navigation-drawer-with-swipe-tabs-using-design-support-library/) for that. It uses FrameLayout + Navigation in MainActivity and attaches a fragment with the FrameLayout. This fragment has TabLayout. Now I have a button in one of the Tab's fragment which will open another fragment. I want to display `back arrow` button in this new fragment. I disabled drawertoggle but unable to show back button. But my app crashes with a NullPointerException. Is there any other way to show the arrow button and also use it to go to previous fragment?

Comment: post your code pls

Answer (score 0):

Before you call commit(), however, you might want to call addToBackStack(), in order to add the transaction to a back stack of fragment transactions. This back stack is managed by the activity and allows the user to return to the previous fragment state, by pressing the Back button.

**Example:**

```
FragmentTransaction tx = fragmentManager.beginTransation();
tx.replace( R.id.fragment, new MyFragment() ).addToBackStack( "tag" ).commit();
```

**My solution:**

main menu xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:orderInCategory="100"
      app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item android:id="@+id/my_back_arrowID"
      android:icon="@drawable/arrow_left"
      android:visible="false"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom">


</item>
```

MainActivity:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (id == R.id.my_back_arrowID) {

        onBackPressed();


    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Your fragment where you want the back arrow to be visible:

```
 @Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.findItem(R.id.my_back_arrowID).setVisible(true);


    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: ah, ok didnt know that you have it since you didnt post any code before

Comment: Its the same as in the link given. I just used as method `replaceFragment(Fragment fragment)` of MainActivity to open a new fragment from TabLayout's fragment. I want to have the back button in NewFrag fragment.

Comment: but why are you adding null to your backstack?

Comment: You can add null if you don't want to pass any string. Anyway, I would like to know how to show the back button in NewFrag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992216/android-fragment-handle-back-button-press

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113013/discussion-between-sam-and-nenco).

Comment: I didnt try your code but I saw in the topic that I just gave you that the accepted answer is adding tag of the fragment to the backstack