# Setting a another view to load when touch back(hard key) in android

Tags: android

I want to navigate to another screen when user touch back button. I found a method for this.

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// do something on back.
return;
}
```

**I'm navigating from a fragment**.But it is not clear that where I have to use this and how. Please help.

Comment: It is always bad approach to launch another screen on device back button press event. Because back button is made to remove the current Activity from the stack and go back to previous Activity (if any)

Answer (score 0):

Just override the method onBackPressed and navigate to the screen you want to via intents or whichever way you prefer.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction.replace(thisfragment,new Fragment).commit();
}
```

The above code will replace your current fragment with the new fragment to which you want to navigate.

Comment: how use this in a fragment

Comment: The same thing, override the method and in the method open a new fragment or pop an old one from the stack, whatever you want to do.

Comment: not showing onBackPressed method. how to and where to write it

Comment: what is your class extending?

Comment: extending Fragment

Comment: Try the above code, it works, place the onBackPressed method inside your class extending fragment

Comment: `onBackPressed()` not showing in fragment to override.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add that method to the Activity class of the screen you're navigating *from*. 
Then, in that method, add your intent code to move *to* your second Activity (let's call that Activity2 below) using startActivity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, Activity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: how use this in a fragment

Comment: Your original question before editing didn't mention fragments. Your fragment should be attached to an activity, though . If you add this to the activity the fragment is attached to it should give you the desired result. Otherwise, you could try the solution in the accepted answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992216/android-fragment-handle-back-button-press