# back button issue in Android app

Tags: android, mobile

I own a mobile android app on google playstore "Geology of India". However, I am not able to switch to the main screen on back press event. Currently, this app has exit option instead.

I have the following screens:

1) Splash screen
2) Main category screen which connects to PHP Json to get all categories.
3) If I click on any of the category button, then it goes to the content page, which displays images and text combination.

Now, if I click on back button of android device, then it will ask you to exit the app. How do I move back from third screen to second / parent screen?

I have tried various methods, but it simply exits the main app or terminates.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtrTP.jpg)

Comment: please don't post images for your code, post formatted code instead.

Comment: Looks like you're using fragments, and it may be a duplicate with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992216/android-fragment-handle-back-button-press

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be overriding `onBackPressed()`.

You don't need to override `onBackPressed()` in order to start the previous activity. the default implementation `finish()`es the current activity and the previous activity in the stack is shown automatically.

Also make sure you are starting the *Content* activity from your *Main* activity without any flags, and that you are not calling `finish()` in your main activity after starting your *Content* activity. What you want to do is just default behavior and you don't need to dig into anything.