# Back to Previous Fragment(setOnClickListener) is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

Ysd i posted one post here but it seems doesn't solve my problem. I also look for similar post in stackoverflow, but it doesn't work for me as well. In this post, i think i have to explain in details of what i want to achieve.

Basically, I have 2 Fragments in 1 activity. From the following screenshot, when user enter sth and click button in Fragment 1, it will reach Fragment 2 .

What i want to do is that in Fragment 2, **when user click the Back button at the top left hand corner OR press the device back button, it will back to previous Fragment (Fragment 1).**

[image]

**two.java**

```
public class two extends Fragment{
TextView get_display_input;
ImageView get_back_button;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
}

public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    get_display_input=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.display_input);
    get_back_button=(ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.back_button);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    String get_name = bundle.getString("input_name_value");
    get_display_input.setText("You have entered "+get_name);

    get_back_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){

            FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
            getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
            transaction.commit();

        }
    });
}
}
```

The above coding is Fragment two. When i try to use

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

It doesn't work.. Please help.

Comment: I think it should help you, take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992216/android-fragment-handle-back-button-press

Comment: I can replace the fragment and click the button will back to Fragment 1. But when i click the device Back button, it will exit the activity but not back to previous fragment

Comment: pls show code that you add fragment.