# Remove only fragment when back pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I create sample app to show some data to user when user start specific activity and click on specific button the app start new fragment (only **fragment** added to activity for now ) my problem is when user click back the **fragment** and the activity removed and go to parent activity. using this code to do that

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.popBackStack();
```

also I use the same code in another action when user click in specific button fragment and back correctly.
Can anyone help me to solve that

Comment: handle onBackPresse()

Comment: add the fragment to the back stack and it will work automatically, you won't have to worry about the back pressed then.

Comment: there are a number or related question in the sidebar [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7992472/2900127)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

override onBackPressed() and remove fragment. Back stack for fragments works differently as it stores transaction not fragments. So can not pop back a fragment but a transaction

Answer (score 14):

Add fragments to back stack when create them and override `onBackPressed` in your activity.

**To add fragment**

```
FragmentManager mFragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.addToBackStack("tag of fragment");
ft.add("your container id", fragment);
ft.commit();
```

**onBackPress**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
       mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
    else super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove only fragment you have to add that fragment in `addToBackStack(TAG)` so that when you press back it popout only Fragment which are added to stack

Answer (score 1):

This is work for me to handle backpressin a fragment in a fragment to remove backstack.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (getView() == null) {
        return;
    }

    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {

            if (keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked Back", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                getActivity().finish();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```