# How to close a fragment when back button is pressed?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have an activity wherein if i click the "BUY" button, it will open a fragment about (150x150 pixels) to ask for the "quantity". If the user will press the back button, it will just simply close the fragment. Any Ideas about closing the fragment?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with-  detecting the back button or removing the fragment?  Either you should have no problem finding dozens of examples on

Comment: Just for confirmation. Are you trying to use fragment for a dialog box?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Fragment handle back button press](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992216/android-fragment-handle-back-button-press)

Comment: the fragment is within the activity. it is not a dialog box. the fragment has an edit text to enter the number of quantity and with "OK" button.

Comment: @nerdykid So basically you are trying to use fragment as a dialog box (150X150 means its a clear dialog box) just to take an input?

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-prompt-user-input-dialog-example/

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/04/android-user-input-dialog-example.html

Comment: Do tell me if you need more references to achieve your result with simple dialog instead of a fragment.

Comment: @Mohammed Atif yes. But I don't know why the problem now is that i'm using a fragment.? it functions well. the problem is just when I press the back button it should remove the fragment.

Comment: my question is simple. i don't need to rework what I've done.

Comment: OK, I will tell you the problem, Fragment has higher impact on memory and performance when compared to Dialog. For your fragment issue, I have already marked a duplicate question. But ideally I must you suggest a better solution. Right?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do it in a fragment it's too much for this simple use, i suggest you to use a PopupWindow:

When you click on Buy Button, you show the popup.

PopupWindow is enough customizable to make your layout as you want

here an example : https://android--code.blogspot.com/2016/01/android-popup-window-example.html

Comment: What happens if the user pressed the back button while the popupwindow is still open? will it automatically close?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use Fragment instead of dialog as suggested and want to remove it, keep a reference to it when creating it and then use `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit()` (you can also `detach` instead of remove if you only want to detach it from the activity but not destroy it completely).

Answer (score 0):

Use popbackstack on backpress of activty by overriding it.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```