# Go to previous fragment pressing physical back button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-gridview

I've created a fragment that shows gridview and when any griditem is clicked it leds to another fragment. But when I press the physical backbutton the app closes instead of going back to previous fragment (i.e. fragment containing gridview). How can I solve this?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992216/android-fragment-handle-back-button-press

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement onBackPressed() in Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-fragments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ){
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    'addToBackStack' is used for moving back to previous fragment, you can use a common Function

    in your Main activity for changing fragment.




public void change_fragment(Fragment fragment, int frame) {


    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
    //trans.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enterfrom_left, R.anim.exit_to_right,R.anim.enterfrom_left, R.anim.exit_to_right);
    trans.replace(frame, fragment);
    trans.addToBackStack("hai" + frame);
    trans.commit();


  }



  you can call it from Main activity like this

  change_fragment(new Frag(),R.id.fl_main_frag_container);



  you can call it from another fragment like this

  ((MainActivity)getContext()).change_fragment(new Frag(), R.id.fl_main_frag_container);
```