# Switch between Fragments in BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I'm working with a simple app with Bottom Navigation View. I have 3 fragments (layout and java). I have BottonNavigationView, declared in my MainActivity.java. My bottonnavigation have 3 items, for the 3 fragments. So, in my MainActivity.java, when i select a item, it start one fragment. So, when i select again another item, nothing happens, because in the java fragment i need to declare the BottonNavigationView, but i don't know how to set it to switch the actual fragment with another fragment.
I tried this link, but no success: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

Sorry my bad english

Here the codes:

Main Activity

```
 @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    Fragment selectedFragment = null;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.navigation_home:
            selectedFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
            selectedFragment = DashboardFragment.newInstance();
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_notifications:
            selectedFragment = NotificationsFragment.newInstance();
            break;
    }
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.content, selectedFragment);
    transaction.commit();
    return true;
}
```

Fragment Java Example

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
public static HomeFragment newInstance() {
HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
return fragment;
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_home, container, false);
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_home, container, false);
}
```

Comment: why you always create new instance?

Comment: in my main_activity layout, i have a linearlayout with FrameLayout and BottomNavigationView, i think i need to create a new instance, no ?

Comment: you can create fragments just once, and you can use them again.

Comment: Can you show me a code ? and how i will switch between fragments on item selected ?

Comment: For example, 
 Fragment homeFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
  Fragment notificationsFragment = NotificationsFragment.newInstance();

And in switch case, you can set selectedFragment = homeFragment or something else

Comment: @TonyStarkus according to this your showed code is correct. First: Do you have data to show in other `fragments`? Second: For which layout is id `content`? Your issue is somewhere in rest of the code

Comment: @Yupi I have just a TextView for the fragments (the text is the fragment name). The id content is the framelayout in my activity_main.xml layout

Comment: @TonyStarkus then check your xml in menu folder are you putting right one in  `BottomNavigationView` and also are id from your menu correct? If that is correct then update your question with xml code of your `activity_main` and of your `MainActivity`

Comment: @Thien Huynh solved my problem man. Just one more question: i have three fragments (Home, Dashboard and Notifications). The Home fragment is the principal menu of my app. So, if i am in Dashboard or Notifications, and i press the button, i want to set the onKeyDown to back for Home Fragment, and, in home fragment, if i press back button, i want to close de app. ou know how to do that ?

Comment: @TonyStarkus override `onBackPressed()` and implement desired code

Comment: Like this :@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            HomeFragment.newInstance();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

Comment: Oh man, this code don't work. I will create another question in the forum. Thank you so much for the help !!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try it:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    Fragment selectedFragment = null;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.navigation_home:
            selectedFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
            selectedFragment = DashboardFragment.newInstance();
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_notifications:
            selectedFragment = NotificationsFragment.newInstance();
            break;
    }
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, selectedFragment).commit();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Wow man, looks like is working, thank you. Just one more question: i have three fragments (Home, Dashboard and Notifications). The Home fragment is the principal menu of my app. So, if i am in Dashboard or Notifications, and i press the button, i want to set the onKeyDown to back for Home Fragment, and, in home fragment, if i press back button, i want to close de app. ou know how to do that ?

Comment: If you want transition between Fragments, call addToBackStack(). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992216/android-fragment-handle-back-button-press

Comment: Thanks @Thien, is a lot of codes but i will try them. Thanks

Comment: @ThienHuynh how do you set the fragment initially on the first run?

Comment: @RazorHead navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
With item 0 it mean HomeFragment is the first.

Comment: @ThienHuynh sorry but I meant to ask how do you load the initial fragment the first time activity starts. your suggestion activates the bottom nav.

Comment: Wait how is this any different than the OP mentioned in his question ? Am I missing something ? I can't see any difference.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to create newInstance every time. you can save the fragment states. follow the below link

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(toBeHidden).show(toBeShown).commit();
```

https://medium.com/@oluwabukunmi.aluko/bottom-navigation-view-with-fragments-a074bfd08711

Answer (score 2):

In this case is better to try get exist fragment from `fragmentManager` like `fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag)`. You can switch more smoothly and you don't need for example load some content from network (if you have such code in fragment or presenter of fragment)

Answer (score 0):

You should create once newIstance from each your Fragments. and later you can hide active fragment and then show new fragment.

```
    Fragment activeFragment;
    ArrayList<Fragment> fragment;

public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment selectedFragment = null;
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_fragment:
                    selectedFragment = ShowMyFragment.newInstance();
                    replaceFragment(selectedFragment);
                    return true;
}
});
    private void replaceFragment(Fragment selectedFragment) {
        boolean lastOpened = false;
        for ( int i=0; i<fragment.size();i++ )
        {
            if ( fragment.get(i) == selectedFragment ) {
                lastOpened = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!lastOpened) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, selectedFragment).commit();
        }
        else
        {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(activeFragment).show(selectedFragment).commit();
        }

        activeFragment = selectedFragment;
    }
```

Comment: Not working if you change toolbar in fragments. After screen rotation toolbar menus are overlaying

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a blank implementation like this in onCreate
bottomNavView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {}

Answer (score 0):

My full solution, I think will be usefull for juniors:

So, we have MainActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

class MainMenuActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

  val bottomNav: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_naviagtion)
  bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener)

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
         supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(
              R.id.fragment_container,
             HomeFragment()
         ).commit()
     }
 }

 private val navListener: BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener =
      BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
         var selectedFragment: Fragment? = null
         when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.bottom_home -> selectedFragment =
            HomeFragment()
        R.id.bottom_events -> selectedFragment =
            EventFragment()
        R.id.bottom_contacts -> selectedFragment =
            ContactsFragment()
        R.id.bottom_menu -> selectedFragment =
            MenuFragment()
    }
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(
        R.id.fragment_container,
        selectedFragment!!
     ).commit()
     true
 }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_naviagtion"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_naviagtion"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow"/>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_naviagtion"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Each fragment class looks like:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
   override fun onCreateView(
       inflater: LayoutInflater,
       container: ViewGroup?,
       savedInstanceState: Bundle?
   ): View? {
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
   }
 }
```

.xml file  for HomeFragment (fragment_home.xml) looks like (other fragments looks the same):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/home"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

NavigationBottomMenu .xml looks (bottom_menu.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/bottom_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/home_selector"
    android:title="Home" />


<item
    android:id="@+id/bottom_events"
    android:icon="@drawable/events_selector"
    android:title="Events" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/bottom_contacts"
    android:icon="@drawable/contacts_selector"
    android:title="Contacts"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/bottom_menu"
    android:icon="@drawable/menu_selector"
    android:title="Menu" />

</menu>
```

Used icons from drawble folder were imported like Vector Asset