# how to handle onback pressed in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

This is my fragment but i want to handle the back button when pressed i want to perform some action on it.

public class BusinessDetail extends Fragment {

```
    public TextView headlineSecond;
    String headline;        

    public BusinessDetail() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_business_detail, container, false);

        headline =getArguments().getString("headline");

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        headlineSecond = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_headline_second_business);


        headlineSecond.setText(headline);
    }

    public boolean onBackPressed() {
        Log.d("ashu","back button pressed");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting something in the log ?

Comment: similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5448653/2949966

Comment: @Ayusch no i am not getting something

Comment: @ahasbini i tried all the methods but onback pressed function is not working

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this article :
[Android Fragment Handle back pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992216/android-fragment-handle-back-button-press)

It involves listening to on KEY_BACK pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to manage backpress :

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        try {
                view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                view.requestFocus();
                view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                              //other stuff
                                return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```