# How to handle overlapping in fragment on back pressed?

Tags: android, fragment

I am facing two  issue in on back pressing in fragment .

First issue is , in my activity i have main fragment in that when i click the  button it is replaces the another fragment B.

In B fragment i have three button, clicking on each button is replaced by three fragments.Fragment C, Fragment D, Fragment E.

In Fragment C i have  Fragment F. In Fragment F I have button when it clicked it moves to Fragment G.

In Fragment G i used `PopBackStack()` method to move to Fragment B. It is moved successfully. But when i click the Fragment D and Fragment D is viewed successfully. When i back pressed in Fragment D it moves to the Fragment G, then it goes to Main Fragment.

I need to Move Fragment Fragment B when back pressed in Fragment D.

**The code in Fragment C,D,E**

```
customerSearchLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Fragment_Money_Transfer_Pin fragment = new Fragment_Money_Transfer_Pin();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });

        mtChargesLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                    Fragment_MoneyTransfer_Charges fragment = new Fragment_MoneyTransfer_Charges();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
        });

        paymentReports.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("number","0");
                Fragment_MoneyTransfer_History fragment = new Fragment_MoneyTransfer_History();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
```

The code for back pressing in Fragment G

```
   getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, ldf).commit();
                    getFragmentManager().popBackStack(Fragment_MoneyTransfer_Home.class.getSimpleName(),
                            FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

                    Fragment_New_Money_Transfer fragment = new   Fragment_New_Money_Transfer();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
              //      fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack( Fragment_Money_Transfer_Mobile.class.getSimpleName() );
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

2) My second issue is the fragment is back pressed is overlapped.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: check out this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7992472/6219121