# onBackPressed() is not working in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onbackpressed

I want to completely it goes to the home of the phone when i back, but `onBackPressed()` is not working. 
My Page is a fragment btw.

Comment: Hi @Jam , please try this link for the `Fragment` **backPress** functionlity (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992216/android-fragment-handle-back-button-press)

Comment: Fragment does not have `onBackPressed` callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getActivity().onBackPressed();` in your fragment it will execute `onBackPressed()` of your parent activity

to be more accurate

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity != null) {
        activity.onBackPressed();}
```

edit: use `requireActivity()` for avoiding nullpointer

```
requireActivity().onBackPressed();
```

Answer (score 1):

onBackPressed callback is handled by your parent activity. So you can override callback on parent activity

XyzActivity.java:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    handleBackPress();
}


public void handleBackPress() {
    Fragment visibleFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentFrameLayout);
    if (visibleFragment == null) {
        return;
    }else if (visibleFragment instanceof PreviewFragment) {
        CommonFunctions.showDialogActionable(this, "Confirm", "Are you sure you want to exit?",
            "Yes", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                finish();
            }, "No", null, "", null, true);
        return;
    }else
        finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```