# Implement Back Pressed In Android Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I've been stuck in a situation and i need some help over here. There are many articles on this topic here but none of them answered my question. I want to implement **onBackPressed()** in `fragments` and show `dialog` box which shows to exit the application or not. Any help would be appreciated.

**LoginFragment.java**

```
    public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String TAG = LoginFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private EditText mEtEmail;
    private EditText mEtPassword;
    private Button mBtLogin;
    private TextView mTvRegister;
    private TextView mTvForgotPassword;
    private TextInputLayout mTiEmail;
    private TextInputLayout mTiPassword;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    private CompositeSubscription mSubscriptions;
    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login,container,false);
        mSubscriptions = new CompositeSubscription();
        initViews(view);
        initSharedPreferences();
        return view;
    }
    private void initViews(View v) {

        mEtEmail = v.findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        mEtPassword = v.findViewById(R.id.et_password);
        mBtLogin = v.findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        mTiEmail = v.findViewById(R.id.ti_email);
        mTiPassword = v.findViewById(R.id.ti_password);
        mProgressBar = v.findViewById(R.id.progress);
        mTvRegister = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_register);
        mTvForgotPassword = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_forgot_password);

        mBtLogin.setOnClickListener(view -> login());
        mTvRegister.setOnClickListener(view -> goToRegister());
        mTvForgotPassword.setOnClickListener(view -> showDialog());
    }

    private void initSharedPreferences() {

        mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    }

    private void login() {

        setError();

        String email = mEtEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = mEtPassword.getText().toString();

        int err = 0;

        if (!validateEmail(email)) {

            err++;
            mTiEmail.setError("Email should be valid !");
        }

        if (!validateFields(password)) {

            err++;
            mTiPassword.setError("Password should not be empty !");
        }

        if (err == 0) {

            loginProcess(email,password);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {

            showSnackBarMessage("Enter Valid Details !");
        }
    }

    private void setError() {

        mTiEmail.setError(null);
        mTiPassword.setError(null);
    }

    private void loginProcess(String email, String password) {

        mSubscriptions.add(NetworkUtil.getRetrofit(email, password).login()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(this::handleResponse,this::handleError));
    }

    private void handleResponse(Response response) {

        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(Constants.TOKEN,response.getToken());
        editor.putString(Constants.EMAIL,response.getMessage());
        editor.apply();

        mEtEmail.setText(null);
        mEtPassword.setText(null);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),  HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    private void handleError(Throwable error) {

        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (error instanceof HttpException) {

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

            try {

                String errorBody = ((HttpException) error).response().errorBody().string();
                Response response = gson.fromJson(errorBody,Response.class);
                showSnackBarMessage(response.getMessage());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {

            showSnackBarMessage("No Internet Connection!");
        }
    }

    private void showSnackBarMessage(String message) {

        if (getView() != null) {

            Snackbar.make(getView(),message,Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void goToRegister(){

        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        RegisterFragment fragment = new RegisterFragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentFrame,fragment,RegisterFragment.TAG);
        ft.addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }

    private void showDialog(){

        ResetPasswordDialog fragment = new ResetPasswordDialog();

        fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), ResetPasswordDialog.TAG);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mSubscriptions.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ResetPasswordDialog.Listener {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private LoginFragment mLoginFragment;
    private ResetPasswordDialog mResetPasswordDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            loadFragment();
        }
    }
    private void loadFragment() {

        if (mLoginFragment == null) {

            mLoginFragment = new LoginFragment();
        }
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentFrame, mLoginFragment, LoginFragment.TAG).commit();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        String data = intent.getData().getLastPathSegment();
        Log.d(TAG, "onNewIntent: " + data);

        mResetPasswordDialog = (ResetPasswordDialog) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ResetPasswordDialog.TAG);

        if (mResetPasswordDialog != null)
            mResetPasswordDialog.setToken(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPasswordReset(String message) {

        showSnackBarMessage(message);
    }

    private void showSnackBarMessage(String message) {

        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.activity_main), message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

In My `Login Fragment`, I want to show a dialog box **"Do you want to exit the application or not"**. On `Yes` it dismiss the current fragment and end the activity otherwise it'll remain active. Help please!

Comment: this question is already answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/7992472/6559031

Comment: I saw that before but nothing is working. Can you edit the code and help me out as i'm new in android. Thanks alot!

Comment: my fragment is not based on multiple stacks. Its a single fragment like Activity. I want it to show dialog box on back pressed.!

Comment: i can show you the layout if you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can even try this way

**MainActivity.java**

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (getFragmentManager() != null && getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() >= 1) {

   String fragmentTag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container).getTag();

   if(fragmentTag.equals(LoginFragment.getTag())){
    // show Dialog code
      }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
      }

    } else {
         super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Add this code in your main activity so that when login fragment is added and you click backpress, then on first if the fragment is added to fragment transaction, then first it finds the fragment and check if its tag is equals to the login fragment tag. Then if both tag matches, then you can show your exit alert dialog.

Comment: i tried this but if(fragmentTag.equals(LoginFragment.getTag())) this shows : getTag() cannot be referenced from a static context. I tried using TAG directly. I have TAG string in LoginFragment. None of it works. Can you help ?

Comment: i have edited your code and fixed the issue. Thanks for the help buddy.! :) Cheers!

Comment: Even you can add custom tag in place of Loginfragment.getTag() when you add fragment in transaction and can compare with that string tag.

Answer (score 0):

Android team has prepared a new way of handling the back button pressed on Fragments for us, so you should check this out. It's called [OnBackPressedDispatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcher).

You need to register [OnBackPressedCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedCallback.html) to the fragment where do you want to intercept back button pressed. You can do it like this inside of the Fragment:

```
     @Override
     public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
         super.onAttach(context);
         OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
             @Override
             public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                //show exit dialog
             }
         };
         requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
     }
```

Comment: i'll surely look. Thanks! :)

Comment: i've used this method inside OnCreateView of fragment but it shows requireActivity is not found. What should i do ?

Comment: Try to replace `requireActivity()` with `getActivity()`.

Comment: after replacing with getActivity() it shows getOnBackPressedDispatcher not found :(

Comment: Do you have your project migrated to AndroidX?

Comment: Which instance of Activity do you use for your project? Are you using `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: i'm trying to use this code in my fragment and yes i'm using AppCompatActivity

Comment: Can you somehow give me access to your project or something? So I can check it out. My code should work, I've tried it on my project.

Comment: i can share mainactivity with you and homefragment with xml. Is it ok ?

Comment: It would be better if I could have access to the whole code. My guess is that you don't have libraries with this feature included in your project. Or you need to update your libraries.